# Unity2D Tile Physics

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some tiles that the Player can navigate on and interact by hitting them with his head from below them. Basically when jumping they can hit a tile, that tile will go up a bit and come back down to it's initial position.

Since the tiles don't have a RigidBody2D because they need to be suspended in air, I took the following approach to the Tile moving up and down:

## Current functionality

**Tile.cs**

*Detect collision with Player's head*

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player Head")
    {
        collidedPlayer = true;

        Vector2 upperPosition = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + .40f);
        StartCoroutine(MovingBlock(0.35f, transform.position, upperPosition));

        isLethal = false;
    }
```

}

*Move Tile*

```
IEnumerator MovingBlock(float time, Vector2 startpos, Vector2 endpos)
{
    float elapsedTime = 0;

    while (elapsedTime < time)
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(startpos, endpos, (elapsedTime / time));
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        isLethal = true;

        yield return null;
    }

    elapsedTime = 0f;

    while (elapsedTime < time)
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(endpos, startpos, (elapsedTime / time));
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        isLethal = false;

        yield return null;
    }

    isLethal = false;
}
```

## The Problem

There are cases where multiple tiles are stacked on top of each other, when Player jumps and hits one tile, that tiles must also hit the tile on top of it and so on for eventual other tiles on top.

- I've tried detecting the tile on top and eventually triggering the Coroutine for it as well but it doesn't seem to detect the collision:

*Layer 8 being Tile layer - I'm checking for isLethal since I now that's when the tile below is jumping*

```
 private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    // print("Layer: " + collision.gameObject.layer);
    // print("Name: " + collision.gameObject.name);
    // print("Is lethal: " + isLethal);

    if (collision.gameObject.layer == 8 && isLethal)
    {
        print("tile to tile");
        Vector2 upperPosition = new Vector2(collision.transform.position.x, collision.transform.position.y + .40f);
        StartCoroutine(MovingBlock(0.35f, collision.transform.position, upperPosition));
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure this out, I've even experimented with adding a RigidBody and no Gravity Scale but that has it's issues. I'm open to any kind of fix, even a different logic.

Answer (score 0):

are you building levels or randomly generating them? If you're building them you should be able to just make a longer collider down to the lowest hittable tile for each tile you want to be affected. If you're randomly generating maybe try sending a raycast from each tile checking for other hittable tiles and sending a function call between them selves when the hit occurs to start the move block coroutine.